# Varied registration form for different Joomla user types

Tags: joomla

I have two user groups: customers and vendors. At the time of basic registration I have a radio button which allows me to put a new user into the respective user groups.

Once the user (customer or vendor) logs in I need one additional registration form for each of them so that (s)he can give specific details such as a customer will have to give vehicle details, while a vendor will have to give his/her bank details.

So how do I get/create two different additional registration forms after login? I am using Joomla 2.5.

Comment: This question is too broad for Stack Overflow, and I am going to try to close it.

Answer (score 1):

Unless you're going to use a community component of some kind like CB or JomSocial, I believe you'll have to write a [custom profile plugin](http://docs.joomla.org/Creating_a_profile_plugin) to make the distinction yourself.

The [Joomla Extension Directory for Communities](http://extensions.joomla.org/extensions/clients-a-communities/comomunities) has a long list of possibilities that you can review to see which best suits your needs.

Comment: but when i try to create a customer profile plugin at the installation time joomla shows an error failed to write the file.. and can i have a different database for it too?? does anyone have any code related to it if done??

Comment: can u give me a little information as of wat is CB or JomSocial cauz i dint use any of them

Comment: Added a link to my answer for you to look at